# Spring boot - Send the refresh token in a cookie

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-boot

I'm developing a angularjs application with a microservices backend.
The microservices are developed using spring boot and are secured with oauth2. I already created an Authorization service and several resources services.
It is possible to request an access token using the password grant, the resources services check the token with the authorization service and validate that the requestor has enough access rights to access the resources.

Now I want to add the refresh token flow to the application. It is very simple to send the refresh token to the browser and just request a new access token from the authorization server. But this exposes the refresh token in the browser (SessionStorage). This seems like a bad idea. So I was wondering whether it is possible to send the refresh token in a secured cookie created in the authorization service. This would prevent javascript access to the refresh token.

Is it possible to send the refresh token in a cookie?

Comment: Did you find solution for this ? I need the same way of implementation in my application